# Shortening a function to have less repetitiveness

Tags: python

```
people = {
    'Thomas' : 'Asian and sly',
    'Kota' : 'Mature and carefree',
    'Seira' : 'Talented and honest',
    'Rika' : 'Energetic and Adventurous',
    'Josh' : 'Mysterious and bluntly honest',
    'Mizuho' : 'Cute and friendly',
    'Daniel' : 'Funny and smart'
}



def qualities():
    print "There are five of my friends.  Which one would you like to know     about?"
    print """
1. Thomas
2. Kota
3. Seira
4. Rika
5. Josh
6. Mizuho
7. Daniel
"""

person = raw_input ('> ')

if "Thomas" in person or "thomas" in person or "1" in person:

    print "Thomas is : ", people['Thomas']

elif "Kota" in person or "kota" in person or "2" in person:
    print "Kota is : ", people['Kota']

elif "Seira" in person or "seira" in person or "3" in person:
    print "Seira is : ", people['Seira']

elif "Rika" in person or "rika" in person or "4" in person:
    print "Rika is : ", people['Rika']

elif "Josh" in person or "josh" in person or "5" in person:
    print "Josh is : ", people['Josh']

elif "Mizuho" in person or "mizuho" in person or "6" in person:
    print "Mizuho is : ", people['Mizuho']  

elif "Daniel" in person or "daniel" in person or "7" in person:
    print "Daniel is : ", people['Kota']

else:
    print "Please choose a friend of mine."
    qualities()

qualities()
```

This code asks for an input of what friend they want to know about and then spits out the qualities that is defined in 'people'.  I just want to know if this is the most efficient way of doing a program like this, since it was kind of tedious to type out all the conditions the user might enter into the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You're right to try to reduce repetition, especially of information. The function could look something like:

```
def qualities():
    while True:
        names = people.keys()
        for index, name in enumerate(names, 1):
            print '{}: {}'.format(index, name.capitalize)
        person = raw_input(' > ').lower()
        if person in names:
            print people[person]
            break
        elif person.isdigit() and int(person) - 1 in range(len(names)):
            print people[names[int(person)-1]]
            break
        else:
            print 'Please enter a name or number.'
```

Note that the name keys in `people` should be all-lowercase for this to work. I have also used a `while` loop rather than recursion to implement it.

---

As a dictionary is an **unordered** data structure, the names may come out in a different order to the one you expect. If order is important, consider a list of two-tuples `(name, description)`:

```
people = [
    ('Thomas', 'Asian and sly'),
    ...
]
```

This retains the order you want. You can always build a dictionary from it at run-time for fast access by name:

```
named_people = {name: description for (name, description) in people}
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion.You can use this

```
mylist = ["Thomas", "thomas", "1"]
if any(i in person for i in mylist):
    print "Thomas is : ", people['Thomas']
```